# How to import image dataset from folder with tensorflowio

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, import, deep-learning, imagedata

Hi I have image dataset from sharing folder. The dataset path like this: /media/sharing_folder/data and data folder has two subfolder which are "masked", "unmasked". I try to import data like this:

```
data = []

def create_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path =  os.path.join(DATADIR, category) #path to masked or unmasked dir
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            
create_data()
```

However, this import is very slowly run. I want to import data with tensorflowio. How can I import with tensorflowio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show your code properly start a new line. On your keyboard depress the key in the upper left  corner (the key just to the right of the 1 key) four times. Then create a new line and enter your code. When finished with entering your code repeat pressing the same key
referenced above four times. This closes out the code area. Here is your code

```
data = []

def create_data(): 
    for category in CATEGORIES: 
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category) #path to masked or unmasked dir 
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category) 
        for img in os.listdir(path): 
            try: img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) 
                data.append([new_array, class_num]) 
            except Exception as e: 
                pass

create_data()
```

Now to answer your question I recommend you use the keras ImageDataGenerator. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

```
split=.2 # set percentage of images to use for validation
height=254 # set to desired image height
width =254 # set to desired image width
batch_size=32 # set to desired batch size
seed = 123  # set to an arbitrary value
data_dir=r'c: /media/sharing_folder/data'
img_gen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255,validation_split=split) 
train_gen=img_gen.flow_from_directory(directory= data_dir,target_size=(height,width),
          color_mode='grayscale', class_mode=categorical, batch_size=batch_size,
          seed=seed, shuffle=True, subset='training)
valid_gen=img_gen.flow_from_directory(directory= data_dir,target_size=(height,width),
          color_mode='grayscale', class_mode=categorical, batch_size=batch_size,
          seed=seed, shuffle=False, subset='validation')
```

then compile your model and use loss as categorical_crossentropy. Then use model.fit
to train your model using the generators defined above
With respect to validation it is best to set shuffle=False in the valid_gen so validation images are provided in the same order for each epoch.

Comment: Hi Gerry. Thanks a lot for your answer. I have a question. I wonder why did you do "shuffle=False" in valid_gen and why didn't use test_datagen?

Comment: see my edited answer. IF yo have a separate test set then create a test_gen like the valid_gen but point it to the directory containing the test data.